# UIImagepickercontroller crash in 4.3.3, using older SDK ( 3.2.5)

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm using UIImagePickercontroller in my app without problems. My SDK version currently is xcode 3.2.5. So far my test devices haven't ran into problems.

One of my testers (at long distance) is experiencing crashes whenever he/she tries to take a picture or choose a picture form the library, after clicking "use" the app crashes. He has IOS 4.3.3 installed. This tester has an 4G iPhone and an iPad, both of them actualized to the latest version, unlike my devices:

iPad 1G with iOS 4.2
iPod 4 with iOS 4.1
iPhone 3G with iOS 4.2.1

The crash doesn't happen on any of my devices.

I realize that i should upgrade my xcode and all my devices soon, but still would like to understand what could be the cause of the crash. I know it's not memory, because my old 3G can choose several pictures without problems, while my tester's iPad and iP4 suffer from consistant crashes every time he tries to select a picture.

Maybe has something to do with HDR ( which i'm not supporting or handling)?, Maybe a deprecated method ?, any important difference that may cause the problem ?.

Any hint or small suggestion to attack the problem is more than welcome. And sorry for my grammar errors.

Thanks !

Comment: there is no obvious issue for crash with IOS4.3, working pretty smoothly for me. posting crash log will help. if not, at least the code snippet can give some idea.

Comment: Interesting that it is _both_ of his devices.  Maybe some other app that is on both devices is interfering?  Ask him to reboot the devices, and then manually close out all of the apps (double-click home and then hold one app, and close all of the apps).  Then have him try your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated the devices and the problems are gone.

Really awful and awkward, the problem is solved but i won't ever know what went wrong !